# Enabling migrations MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Running the following in my package manager console:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Rent-a-Car-MVC.Models.CarDBContext
```

Returns:

```
The context type 'Rent-a-Car-MVC.Models.CarDBContext' was not found in the assembly 'Rent_a_Car_MVC'.
```

While I do have an existing class called `Car.cs` inside the Models folder of my project containing the following code:

```
public class CarDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Wat am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter 'enable-migrations' and you will see a list of available migrations